# WSO2 ESB Carbon application deployment fails

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I have grouped family of services as a `Carbon Application` and then deploying the same on WSO2 ESB. If one of those services fails during deployment then none of the other services are deployed on ESB, instead i get an `Service laready exists` exception upon retry.

It will be of great help if you could help me.

**EDIT**

I am using WSO2 3.0.1.

Comment: What is the ESB version you have used here? Also what do you mean by I'm using WSO2 3.0.1 since it does not make much sense when you mention the product like that. Please let us know the products you are using so that we can assist you to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you donot have any traces of CAR file that you uploaded in the following paths.

```
1) <ESB_HOME>--> tmp--> carbonappuploads
2) <ESB_HOME>--> repository-->deployment-->server-->carbonapps
3) <ESB_HOME>--> carbonapps.
```

After deleting any traces of carbonapps in the above mentioned apps, Restart the ESB server. Then try to upload CAR file again. Hope this will work.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description I guess that you are trying to deploy a Carbon Application aRchive (CAR) file which contains a set of services in WSO2 ESB. First of all I would like to suggest to use WSO2 Application Server [1] to deploy services instead of the ESB.

Regarding the error you get during the deployment I guess you may have defined two services with the same name or you may have already deployed this CAR file before. Hope this will help. If this is not the case please provide more information about your problem so that we could try to identify the problem.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS320/Creating+JAX-WS+and+JAX-RS+Service+Projects

Thanks